# Is there a concise Wordpress function for building a page link from an ID?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently building links like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(111); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(111); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(111); ?></a>
```

I was building links like this using the WPML plugin (but steering away from it due to various reasons):

```
<?php icl_link_to_element(111); ?>
```

This builds a link similar to my first example.

So my question is is there a native Wordpress function that does this? I'm sure there must be, but cannot find the solution anywhere. I'm looking to reduce my markup...

Thanks!

**EDITED WITH ANSWER**

This is how I built my custom function:

```
function build_pretty_link($id,$link_title='') {
    if($link_title=='') {
        $link_title = get_the_title($id);
    }
    $link_url = get_permalink($id);
    echo "<a href=\"{$link_url}\" title=\"{$link_title}\" alt=\"{$link_title}\">{$link_title}</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress give a function that print an anchor tag with the title and the url, but you have to be in a the loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/permalink_anchor).

I suggest you to create your own function (the functions.php file in your theme is here for that).

You can do someting like that :

```
function vp_link_to($post_id) {
  echo '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(111); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>';
}
```

Comment: Ah yes of course. You'd have thought there might be something native to Wordpress though outside the loop... Thanks, I'll do this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
get_permalink(x);
```

Where the ID of the page is **x** and wrap this in whatever you need, so

```
$id = 10;
$link = get_permalink($id);
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Linked text</a>';
```

Comment: Yeah this is probably a neater way of doing what I'm doing, but it doesn't necessarily reduce the markup terribly. Thanks for responding though :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are looking for then. You asked for a native Wordpress permalink function, that is it!